# Title warning message showing, but similar titles list isn't

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, search, user-interface, title

I have found that the Title search is usually better than the search box, so I'll hit the `Ask Question` button, type in a title, and see what comes up on the list.  I just did that for a short title and got the following message *with no list*:

> That title is too short to be useful. Can you add some more detail?

How about giving me that message, **AND** the list?

Comment: Maybe there's too many potential hits in the DB?

Comment: Yeh, that could be.

Comment: I do the same thing, it's quicker than Jeff's solution below and you get real-time results. The real problem is that we're using the "Ask Question" page to do searches. For the amount of content on SO, I feel that a page dedicated to viewing and filtering search **results** with real-time updates would be awesome and extremely effective.

Comment: Workaround: The limit is fifteen characters so just add a word that isn't indexed repeatedly, e.g. "and and and".

Answer (score 2):

If you need to replicate title search, simply use the `title:` operator as documented here:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

`title:apples oranges`

Comment: It doesn't work well for multiple words, for example on SO I tried the search `title:apple title:unix` and `title:apple AND title:unix` and neither search gave me only questions with those two words in the title.  They seemed to key off of the first title search, and ignored the unix term.  And of course the search for `title:"apple unix"` returns nothing because it only returns exact results.

Comment: But I'll admit the Question Title search box doesn't actually work any better when actually tested.